# How to bulk upload Recipient lists in Alibaba Cloud Direct Mail?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-direct-mail

I am using Alibaba Cloud Direct Mail for my project triggering the mails for the events like signup, password reset, etc.. and Batch emails for informing discounts, etc..

I want to show how the recipient lists are uploaded to the Alibaba Cloud console since this information is not available in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the **DirectMail** service in the console
2. You must create at least one **New Recipient List**
3. Click on the **Upload** button under the Action field of the recipient list
4. You can either upload a **.txt** file ([Sample txt file)](http://aliyundm.oss.aliyuncs.com/example/example_en.txt) or **.csv** ([sample csv](http://aliyundm.oss.aliyuncs.com/example/example_en.csv)) file which contains the list of email recipients and other fields
5. Please take note on the limitations such as the maximum number of
   email addresses per recipient list which is **10,000** as of today

[image]

6. After the upload is successful, you can click on the **Details** button
   to view and validate the uploaded recipient email addresses and
   fields
   [image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: What do you mean by SO?

Comment: I meant StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can upload the recipient lists

Navigate to console > select region > send Emails > Recipent Lists

[image: Console]

1. Plain Text files (.txt)
2. Comma Separated  Value files (.csv)

you can download the sample files in the console and edit them and upload

[image: Sample files download]